# Stateful EJB and several client applications

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb

A am writing a `Java EE` application ("UserServices") which provides some services like logging in users, managing users and so on by `EJB` or web services `REST`. `EJB` is intended to be used by the application or by client applications. Client applications use stateless remote (or local) beans provided by the application.

I want to keep data about the number of logged-in users, users' activities and user statistics which are calculated dynamically.

And I do not know how to do it.

The data have to be kept in the "UserServices" application because it its data. So I think I would use stateful beans with local and remote interfaces to keep them. But every client application should cause a change of the data when invoking a service like "log in" or "log out".

So, how to change the state of the data which "live" in the "UserServices" application from the inside of a client application which uses a remote (or local) stateless bean?

Or in other words, how to change the state of a stateful bean existing in an application from within another (possibly remote) application?

I am using `Java EE 6` and `EJB 3.1` and `JBoss 7.1`.

Comment: I think a singleton ejb might be usefull for counting the number of logged-in users.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you would like to share some data between beans invocations from different clients. Trying to access a state of stateful session bean from another isn't a good idea, as there is always created one instance per client. 
If persistence of data isn't necessary, you could use EJB Singleton Bean, or CDI bean with singleton-scope (I prefer EJB Singleton). To monitor users activity(beans invocations), interceptors might be useful, you could intercept SFSB invocations, and feed singleton that way.

Answer (score 0):

To count the number of logged-in users you should define your bean as @Singleton. @Singlton retain the data across the start of container to end.

```
import javax.ejb.Singleton;
@Singleton

public class CounterBean {
private int loginUser = 1;

// Increment and return the number of users
public int countLoggedInUsers() {
    return loginUser++;
}
}
```

To saved permanently logged in user you should use database or file.